# ng-katex is not being installed properly

Tags: angular, katex

I have install ng-katex as per the documentations,But it show the following error:-

```
ERROR in node_modules/ng-katex/lib/ng-katex.component.d.ts:9:28 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDefWithMeta' requires 7 type argument(s).

9     static ngComponentDef: ɵngcc0.ɵɵComponentDefWithMeta<KatexComponent, "ng-katex", never, 
{ 'equation': "equation", 'options': "options" }, { 'onError': "onError" }, never>;
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ng-katex/lib/ng-katex-paragraph.component.d.ts:6:28 - error TS2314: Generic type 
'ɵɵComponentDefWithMeta' requires 7 type argument(s).

6     static ngComponentDef: ɵngcc0.ɵɵComponentDefWithMeta<KatexParagraphComponent, "ng-katex-paragraph", never, { 'paragraph': "paragraph" }, {}, never>;
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ng-katex/lib/ng-katex-html.component.d.ts:12:28 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDefWithMeta' requires 7 type argument(s).

12     static ngComponentDef: ɵngcc0.ɵɵComponentDefWithMeta<KatexHtmlComponent, "ng-katex-html", never, { 'html': "html" }, {}, never>;
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue when imported KatexModule from 'ng-katex/lib/ng-katex.module' instead of 'ng-katex'.